# Can't upgrade El Capitan on DIY Fusion Drive (A partition, not whole disk required)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, osx-el-capitan, fusion-drive

I can only find one post on the entire internet with the same problem as this, so I doubt i'm going to get flooded with answers but basically i'm trying to upgrade a Yosemite Mac mini to El Capitan which is running a DIY Fusion drive.

Its made up of an internal SSD and an external Thunderbolt G-Raid Raid Array (2x 4tb WD Red's) to great an 8.25TB Corestorage volume.

The problem is when I try to upgrade to El Cap i get the error message

"OS X Could not be installed on your computer. A partition, not a whole disk is required for this operation".

I can't even think what its referring to, the fusion drive seems to follow Apple's conventions. It was missing a recovery HD which is the only thing I thought could be an issue so I recreated that, but no luck, still got the same error message.

Anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Did you have any luck so far, or did the fusion configuration, go south?

Comment: No luck @Highmastdon- I tried putting the missing Recovery HD back into the Fusion drive successfully but it made no difference to El Capitan install, still gave me the strange error of "A partition, not a whole disk is required for operation".

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very similar problem with my DIY fusion drive on El Capitan.  The difference being that I can install El Capitan. But, after the first reboot when the OS is fully installed(i.e. can watch YouTube, browse the inet, etc.) The system starts having issues like inet just stops working, and weird things happen. Then I reboot, for the first time, it just boots to the apple symbol with the bar and never shows any progress.  So I split the drive and reinstalled el capitan and everything works fine.

Possible fix is disabling System Integrity Protection (rootless).  This might work for you I am not sure.   The link to it is http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

I am going to give it a shot if it does not work I will repost.

Comment: Disabling SIP might be a good idea, but is it even around in Yosemite to disable before installing?